# MapActivity doesn't work

Tags: android, mapactivity

On my app i have MapActivity but when i launch it on a virtual device or on my cellphone the app doesn't work.
inside the layout i wrote the APIKey.

i'm sure that the problem isn't the code because i'd download an example from an Android book and it doesn't work also.

what is the problem??

thanx,
yoni

Comment: Please describe the problem better and add some code, error log, etc in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to post some code if you can so people have a better idea of what your problem could be.  When I started messing with google maps i used this tutorial

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

That page pretty much told me everything i wanted to know to get started

If was to guess your problem blind it would be that you didn't use the google APIs in your project build

Comment: thanx pasha. the code is an example from a book so the problem is not the code itself for sure, but maybe in the SDK or the Android libraries. Also, i tried the link you suggested and it didn't work for me either.
i read in a forum that there's some kind of problem with the current   libraries of the maps. do you know something about it?

thanx again!